# Deck.Print is only showing 2 of spades have been added to deck list

Tags: c#, playing-cards

So as the title of this question says, my `Deck.Print()` is only showing that 2 of spades have been added.

My theory is that for some reason the cards that are being created in `Deck()` arent changing the suit and face of the card so they stick to the default values of the enums (I assume the default is whatever is 0 in the enum).

From the way I look at it it should be creating the card, casting the Enum type onto I or F, and then adding that card to deck.list. Why is this not working? Thanks.

```
class Deck
{
    public List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

    public Deck() // Generates all cards in the deck
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int f = 0; f < 13; f++)
            {
                Card card = new Card();
                card.Suit = (Suit)i;
                card.Face = (Face)f;
                cards.Add(card);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Print() // prints all cards in the deck , used for testing
    {
        foreach (var card in cards)
        {
            card.Print();
        }
    }
}
enum Suit
{
    Spades,
    Hearts,
    Diamonds,
    Clovers
}

enum Face
{
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace
}

class Card
{
    private Suit suit;
    private Face face;

    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public Face Face { get; set; }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1}", face, suit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problen is thus, you are reading what look originally/suspiciously like *Backing Fields* in your `Print` methods, which inturn has never been set.

If you dont need these fields, just use [Auto Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) like you have, and remove them to save confusion

`public Suit Suit { get; set; }`

**Modified**

```
class Card
{
    // jsut delete these all together
    //private Suit suit; // you are printing this out and never changing it
    //private Face face; // you are printing this out and never changing it

    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public Face Face { get; set; }

    public void Print()
    {
      //  Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1}", face, suit);
      // print your actual properties not the backing fields that have never been set
      Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1}", Face, Suit);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense! Huge oversight on my part. Thank you!!

Comment: Actually the fields are just fields, not *backing fields*.

Comment: In what situations would I need a field and the auto properties? Im making a poker simulator and right now in my Players class I have the samething (private string name and then pubic string Name{get; set;}) should I do the same thing on that one?

Comment: @Yummy275 Generally if you are doing somethign in your getter and setter, you may need a backing field. if youre not, then there is no real need for them these days in modern versions of C# as we have auto properties and dont need to verbosely write out the backing fields

Comment: @Yummy275 The standard pattern to notify a listener about changed properties (via `INotifyPropertyChanged`)  uses explicit backing fields for example (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples))